# jquery fadeTo border problem

Tags: jquery, effects

while fading an element to 0 transparency, the fadeTo command of jquery does not affect the border of this element. is there any solution to solve this problem? i created a demo on: http://jsfiddle.net/V57EF/

Comment: Is fading the table an option? Table borders are....different, as you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/animate/ :

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin,
>   background, border) are not supported.

`fadeTo` seems to be similar in behavior to `animate`.

If you want the border to hide, you could use callback to set it to 0 ( http://jsfiddle.net/V57EF/14/ ):

```
$('td').fadeTo(1000, 0, function(e) { $(this).css({border: "0"}); });
```

Looks ugly, but I can't think of anything better atm.